# Java recursive method to find complement

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to think of how to use recursion to find complement of a number.
For example each digit `x` of a number must become `9 - x`, so `1234 -> 8765`.

I can't really think how to do that. This is my code so far:

```
public static int complement(int n){
    int x = n % 10;
     x = x - 9;
     n = (n / 10) 
    return complement(n,x);
}

public static int complement(int n ,int times){

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're removing relevant parts of your question. They are important as they show the current code, and that effort was made. Please don't vandalize your post (even 1 year old post), it happened in the past for this question.

Answer (score 5):

When you are dealing with recursion, it is important to write the algoritm first in English (or your native tongue :) ).

For this task, consider the following:

- I have an number `n`. Let's take the last digit and subtract this digit to 9.
- Do this again for the rest of the digits, i.e. `n / 10`. With the result obtained, we need to make a number again: so we multiply the result by 10 and add the digit we calculated before. In other words, `complement(n / 10)` returns the complement of the number `n` without the last digit, so we need to append the complement of the last digit to this.
- When the number is less than 10, we have nothing more to do and we can just return `9 - n` (this is the base case, the number is only one digit long).

In code, this is implemented as:

```
public static int complement(int n) {
    if (n < 10) {
        return 9 - n;
    }
    int x = n % 10;
    x = 9 - x;
    return 10 * complement(n / 10) + x;
}
```

and then:

```
System.out.println(complement(1234)); // prints 8765
```

This can be written a bit shorter with:

```
public static int complement(int n) {
    if (n < 10) {
        return 9 - n;
    }
    return 10 * complement(n / 10) + 9 - n % 10;
}
```